# Check whether int value of string is zero, positive or null in Python

Tags: python, django

I am saving the form data into a model instance. There are fields where the user can enter values from 0 and above or leave them empty. Now I should assign them to a field.

Eg code

```
def update(self, my_val):
    self.my_val = my_val or None
```

This above code works fine for values of 1 and above. But not for 0. How can I allow for 0 and positive numbers and if `my_val` is an empty string then I should store it as `None`. How can I do that?

Comment: Both the answers worked but I am selecting the one liner answer because the if condition in that is sufficient for my case since there will be only empty string or 0 and not other falsy values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the ternary operator in Python.

```py
def update(self, my_val):
    self.my_val = None if my_val=='' else my_val
```

This will store `None` if it is empty string(that is what mentioned in Question), otherwise it will store it as it is.

Answer (score 2):

Likely it is more readable here to work with an `if` check, so:

```
def update(self, my_val):
    if not my_val and my_val != 0:
        self.my_val = None
    else:
        self.my_val = my_val
```

The reason this happens is because the `… or …` first checks the first operand and if the *truthiness* is `False`, it returns the second operand. Since the empty string, `None`, and `0` all have truthiness `False`, it thus means that it will in that case use `None`.

Comment: thanks for the clear explanation. I understood it now.